# Power BI Two Non Related Tables. Need to join based on date and return data

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables in Power BI.  I need to return the value from one table based on the the date range and employee_id of the original table.  Can anyone assist me in how to do this?  the Hierarchy_ID changes from Month to Month and is unique to the Employee_ID.  I need to use the Employee_ID look at the Entry_Date and determine the Hierarchy_ID based on the start/end date of the Employee_ID.  Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqfyH.png)

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output in text format.

Comment: yes sure. sorry it is in the link above but the hyper link posted as "enter image description here"

Comment: That is an image. Can you not paste the text so it can be copied by whoever is able to answer your question?